# about triangular rull with functions in python

Tags: python, function, triangular

What's the problem in this code? It looks correct. but outputs are not correct.
by the way, (none of them is greater than or equal to the sum of the other two)
It's triangular rule...

```
import sys

def areTriangular(x,y,z):
    if x<y+z and y<x+z and z<x+y:
        return True
    else:
        return False

a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
c = sys.argv[3]


m = areTriangular(a,b,c)

print(m)
```

Comment: What input do you use? What output do you get? What output do you expect?

Comment: for example, I put 3 4 5 numbers, and output is. False. but it would be True

Comment: You need to convert your input (strings) to numbers (floats or ints).

Comment: oooo. khlelwood. thank you so much it workes. but I am wondering why it couldn't before? because that function not understand that values are numbers?

Comment: If you use `<` on strings then they are compared alphabetically, so the result is different.

Comment: thanks for that information. I didn't know it compared alhabetically. It's very good information. thanks again :)

Answer (score -2):

Is because Python is 0 indexed so you need to use:

```
a = sys.argv[0]
b = sys.argv[1]
c = sys.argv[2]
```

instead of:

```
a = sys.argv[1]
b = sys.argv[2]
c = sys.argv[3]
```

Comment: No it isn't. `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script itself. The arguments start at 1.